# Cable modem suddenly has connectivity problems, captured log: what do these errors indicate?

Tags: internet-connection, isp, cable-modem

Normally our ISP and Internet service works very well and we get speeds up 115MBPS.  Today everything was going great, then suddenly we lose connectivity.
The wireless router is fine.  I log into Cable Modem and I see the following errors:

> 2020-12-16, 09:24:07  Critical (3)    No Ranging Response received - T3
> time-out;CM-MAC=38:94:ed:75:3e:40;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:69:22:6c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
>
> 2020-12-16, 09:23:58  Error (4)   Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV
> Type:
> 17.8;CM-MAC=38:94:ed:75:3e:40;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:69:22:6c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
>
> 2020-12-16, 09:23:58  Error (4)   Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV
> Type:
> 17.9;CM-MAC=38:94:ed:75:3e:40;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:69:22:6c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
>
> 2020-12-16, 09:23:29  Notice (6)  Overriding MDD IP initialization
> parameters; IP provisioning mode = IPv6
>
> 2020-12-16, 09:23:18  Critical (3)    **Received Response to Broadcast
> Maintenance Request**, But no Unicast Maintenance opportunities
> received - T4 time
> out;CM-MAC=38:94:ed:75:3e:40;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:69:22:6c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;
>
> 2020-12-16, 09:22:46  Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging
> -- No Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=38:94:ed:75:3e:40;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:69:22:6c;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;

Previously (8 months ago) I had the ISPs hardware (modem) but since then I bought my own equipment (Netgear CM600).

**I'm wondering**

1. what those errors might indicate? -- if anything
2. if the ISP was sending some kind of maintenance signal thinking it was their modem (even though they know I have my own equipment) and that is causing some error?

Comment: Actually Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV refers to the issue. It means not able to sync network parameters with ISP. I would suggest that you check if you have the updated firmware https://kb.netgear.com/000036375/What-s-the-latest-firmware-version-of-my-NETGEAR-cable-modem-or-modem-router
Firmware upgrades are pushed down by your ISP. After checking with them you may need to update it or change timeout settings that typically lead sync to fail.
In worst case it can be coax issue.

Comment: Speak to your ISP

Comment: @Hardoman  First, thanks for comment with ideas about what might be happening.  I appreciate it.  It feels odd to me that even though I keep the firmware updates on my modem the ISP will push firmware updates to my device?  That really seems odd. Especially to do it in the middle of the day. Not questioning that you're right just doesn't seem like the right process from ISP.  But whoever said they do things right?  :)
edit - Ok, I just read that link (very helpful) wow, that is very interesting to me that ISP handles the router that I own.  All good.  thanks

Comment: @Hardoman Also, I just checked my modem's firmware version and it is correct for my ISP (Spectrum) V1.01.14.  Thanks again, you really helped.

Comment: Just got popular question award for 1,000 views. Zero upvotes.  Always cracks me up. 

Comment: @raddevus ISPs pushing firmware updates is part of the DOCSIS spec; the ISP is supposed to be in control of the firmware. Most (all?) cable modems don't let consumers upgrade the firmware on their own. If your modem has a built in wifi router, you might be able to update that, but the modem side has its own CPU and its own firmware. This is partly why a lot of ISPs have a short list of "approved modems" and nothing else is allowed. Those are the ones they have firmwares and actively test. I think some ISPs might tweak the firmwares sometimes, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s what happened.
When the tech arrived he went directly to the outside drop. He reached inside saw there was a filter (small extension between end connector and incoming coax connection).
He unscrewed the filter threw it on the ground and plugged the coax directly into the connection.

The company switched the frequencies they were broadcasting internet signal on and when they did anyone with this old TV filter on their lines was down.

We waited 48 hours for a 30 second fix.

**2022-01-11**

I noticed the filter the tech removed is still out there so I took a pic.

[image: filter on coax]